# Bound mismatch mitigation

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Say I have a generic interface:

```
interface SomeInterface<T> {
...
}
```

and two implementations:

a specific one (perhaps optimised for `SpecificClass` and its descendents):

```
class SpecificImplementation<T extends SpecificClass> implements SomeInterface<T> {
...
}
```

and another catch all one (perhaps which can handle all types but is very inefficient):

```
class CatchAllImplementation<T> implements SomeInterface<T> {
....
}
```

And I want to have a generic method similar to the following:

```
public <T> SomeInterface<T> getImplementation(Class<T> clazz) {
  if(SpecificClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
  {
    // do some specific stuff

    ...

    // get specific optimised implementation for SpecificClass and descendents
    return new SpecificImplementation<T>(); // bound mismatch error here
  }
  else
  {
     // do other stuff

     ...

     // get inefficient catch all implementation in other cases
     return new CatchAllImplementation<T>();
  }
}
```

Is there any way of mitigating against the bound mismatch error? Some kind of trick to force the compiler to ignore it or similar?

I don't HAVE to bound the type parameter on the specific implementation but I would rather do so.

Comment: Can't you use something like `class SpecificImplementation implements SomeInterface<SpecificClass>` or `class SpecificImplementation<T extends SpecificClass> implements SomeInterface<SpecificClass>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Main {    
    public <T> SomeInterface<T> getImplementation(Class<T> clazz) {
        if(SpecificClass.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz))
        {
            // do some specific stuff

            // unchecked cast here...
            return (SomeInterface<T>) getSpecificImplementation((Class<SpecificClass>) clazz); 
        }
        else
        {
            // do other stuff
            return new CatchAllImplementation<T>();
        }
    }

    private <T extends SpecificClass> SomeInterface<T> getSpecificImplementation(Class<T> clazz) {
        return new SpecificImplementation<T>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();
        SomeInterface<SpecificClass> implementation = m.getImplementation(SpecificClass.class);

        System.out.println("Result: " + implementation.getClass());
        SomeInterface<Object> catchAll = m.getImplementation(Object.class);

        System.out.println("Result: " + catchAll.getClass());

        SomeInterface<SpecificClassChild> implementationForChild = m.getImplementation(SpecificClassChild.class);

        System.out.println("Result: " + implementationForChild.getClass());
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Result: class timo.generics.SpecificImplementation
Result: class timo.generics.CatchAllImplementation
Result: class timo.generics.SpecificImplementation
```

Comment: Will this work for type parameter classes which extend SpecificClass?

Comment: Not sure if I get what you mean, but I tried this: Made a `SpecificImplementationChild<T extends SpecificClass> extends SpecificImplementation<T>`. Return a new instance of this Child in the private `getSpecificImplementation` method. This printed `Result: class timo.generics.SpecificImplementationChild` as the first line instead.

Comment: So what I mean is if `SpecificClass` is abstract and I have a concrete implementation `SpecificClassExtension extends SpecificClass` which I want to use as my type parameter, does `SomeInterface<SpecificClassExtension> implementation = m.getImplementation(SpecificClassExtension.class);` work?

Comment: Updated answer to reflect this, I hope. Also made `SpecificClass` abstract to check, this gives the same results.

Answer (score 0):

That is because SpecificImplementation needs a T that extends SpecificClass.

You can get away with using SpecificImplementation without a type:

```
return new SpecificImplementation();
```

A better solution would be to make use of inheritance rather than using if statements.

Comment: I'm not sure how inheritance would help? I need to use reflection to determine which generic implementation to use based on the type parameter's class.

Comment: I don't know about your use case, but a series of if-statements that check the object instance is usually a bad practice.